# ASP.NET Core - error "unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to developing applications using C# and ASP.NET Core. Currently, I am working on my very first full-stack project.

While setting up an API for my website, I encountered an issue while testing the MySQL server connection. Despite my best efforts to find a solution by searching online, I failed to find any helpful results.

Here's the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Api.Data.DataContext' while attempting to activate 'Api.Controllers.WeatherForecastController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method3(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: text/plain
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:5145
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: Webstorm-e636d691=8234aba1-ab4b-40a9-9f71-76e7daf456c7
Referer: http://localhost:5145/swagger/index.html
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
```

DataContext:

```
using Dapper;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Api.Data
{
    public class DataContext
    {
        private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

        public DataContext(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _connection = new MySqlConnection(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }

        public T LoadSingleData<T>(string sql)
        {
            return _connection.QuerySingle<T>(sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using Api.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Api.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DataContext _dapper;

    public WeatherForecastController(DataContext dapper)
    {
        _dapper = dapper;
    }

    [HttpGet("/testconnection")]
    public string connectionTest()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM testconnection";
        return _dapper.LoadSingleData<string>(sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered the `Dapper` context with the dependency injection container?

Comment: We need to see your configuration code.

Comment: @Peppermintology I don't know how to

Comment: @OzanBAYRAM if you mean program.cs here it is:
`var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();`

Comment: I suspect [one of the many Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=dapper+asp.net+core+dependency+injection) available will be of use.

Answer (score 0):

You've not registered DataContext, so AspNet is unable to provide it to the constructor of WeatherForecastController.  Register it as below ...

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddControllers(); 
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    // Register DataContext in Services ********
    builder.Services.AddScoped<DataContext>();

    var app = builder.Build();
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline. 
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) 
    {     
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(); 
    }  
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();  
    app.UseAuthorization(); 
    app.MapControllers(); 
    app.Run()
```